# Where does the 3 in my prime number list get appended?

Tags: python

I can understand how every other prime number after 3 gets appended because (x%y != 0) but for the first iteration of the for loop it seems that x%y would equal 0. So how does it end up getting appended to my prime list?

```
def count_primes(num):
# edge case: 1 and 0 are not prime numbers
    if num < 2:
        return 0

# create prime list, check length to find amount of primes up to input num
# insert 2 bc it is only even prime number. Allows use of step in range to only iterate odds
    primes = [2]

# create variable that holds prime candidates starting after 2
    x = 3

# proceed into loop if prime candidate is less than or equal to input number
    while x <= num:
# cycle through odd numbers up to input number
        for y in range(3,x,2):
            if x%y == 0:
                x += 2
                break
        else:
            primes.append(x)
            x += 2
    return primes
```

Comment: When `x` is 3, `range(3,x,2)` is an empty range - so no `%` test gets done for that number.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks man you're a god

Answer (score 0):

> When `x` is 3, `range(3,x,2)` is an empty range - so no `%` test gets done for that number.

– [jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364/jasonharper)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59724962/where-does-the-3-in-my-prime-number-list-get-appended#comment105600444_59724962)